# Second order logic theory describable by first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I have a question to the preconditions to describe a second order theory by first order logic.

Consider the second order logic theory of the Natural Numbers $N_{1}=\left(\mathbb{N},+,\cdot\right)$, which is equivalent to the first order theory $N_{2}=\left(P\left(\mathbb{N}\right),E,\mathbb{N},+,\cdot\right)$, where $P\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$ is the powerset of the Natural Numbers.

We added the powerset to the first order universe, so we can quantify over the elements of the powerset.

My question is about the $E$. $E$ is defined as a subset of the Cartesian product between $\mathbb{N}$ and $P\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$, $E\subseteq\mathbb{N}\times P\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$, with the condition $nEr\Longleftrightarrow n\in r$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $r\in P\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$.

For what we need $E$?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: $E$ is interpreted with $\in$ ("to be element of").

Comment: In SOL we have variables for numbers (individual variables), like FOL, but also variables for sets of numbers (unary predicate variables), that in FOL are not available; thus, to mimic SOL with FOL we need a two-sorted logic: one domain for numbers and one for set of numbers and a way to express the link between them ($\in$)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$ is only sufficient to interpret the *monadic* second-order theory of $\mathbb{N}$, i.e. the second-order theory which only allows for second-order variables of arity one (*set variables*, if you like). So your question is really about the relationship between the *monadic* second-order theory of $\mathbb{N}$ and the first-order theory of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

In this context, you need the relation $E$ to interpret atomic formulas of the form $X(t)$ where $X$ is a second-order variable of arity one (a set variable) and $t$ is a term. Such an atomic formula is true in a given interpretation if and only if the number which interprets $t$ lies in the set which interprets $X$. Translating $X(t)$ into a first-order language thus results in $E(t,X)$ (or if you will, $t\,E\,X$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think, I have understood E. A FOL theory can always be interpreted on an countable universe. How could that be? Then P(N) is countable.

Comment: If a first-order theory has an infinite model, then it has a countable model. This does not imply that _every_ model of the theory is countable.

For example, the real numbers (uncountable) and the algebraic real numbers (countable) have the same first-order theory in the signature consisting of addition, multiplication and the constants zero and one, namely the theory of real closed fields.

Comment: Thats my greatest problem in understanding predicate logic. Loosely spoken: "The powerset is not always the real powerset".

Comment: Can you suggest me some literature with examples, where the powerset of a countable infinite set is again countable? What is meant with the powerset in this situations? Waht are the countable algebraic real numbers? What the monadic second order theory?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I am saying. $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is, of course, not countable. What I am saying is that this is in no way in conflict with the fact that "a FOL theory [which has an infinite model] can always be interpreted on an countable universe". Concerning your other questions, here are the relevant definitions:

Algebraic real numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number
Monadic second-order logic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_second-order_logic